# Why some standard fields on Asset object are not available in another org?

Tags: standard-objects, asset

In one of my Developer Sandbox, I am able to use the following fields on Asset Object

```
Uuid 
StatusReason 
ManufactureDate 
ExternalIdentifier
```

While in another Sandbox(Partial Copy),  I get the following error when I try to deploy

```
Could not resolve standard field's name.
```

Is there some feature I need to activate to access above fields?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you figured that out by now, so this is just the explanation for all the fellow googlers that are still wondering.

The `Uuid` standard field (together with `ExternalIdentifier`, `StatusReason` and `ManufacturDate` was released with API Version 49.0. The code that references these fields is certainly lower, this is why it doesn't compile (or the Sandbox in question was a Preview Sandbox on 49, while the other Sandbox was still on 48. I think 49 was released around the time when the original post was written).

That's the reason why the [Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asset.htm) always includes the API version where this field exists, and why crmprogdev didn't find it in his reference (simply switch to the [v48 docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asset.htm) to reproduce).

Answer (score 1):

I don't find those fields listed in the [Object Reference for Asset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asset.htm). I suspect that's the reason you're not able to deploy them.

They may have been added by a managed package or by enabling some Salesforce feature that's not currently enabled in the Partial Copy sandbox. Depending on the details of how you "deploy", they may not be deployable by your CI mechanasm. In essence, for that reason, they appear to you to be "standard fields" but not to the Partial Sandbox. If they were OOTB standard fields, I'd expect them to already be in the Partial Sandbox.

Comment: looks like these fields belong to some specific feature but I was not able to find which feature contains these standard fields for Assets. Recently these days few standard features/settings suddenly appear in Dev sandbox but they are not deployable by TeamCity as target environment don't understand them. This break our CI/CD pipeline

Comment: That happens. I'm working on a Health Cloud deployment right now and the CI/CD program the client uses (Flosum) isn't able to deploy managed packages of any kind. While HC is a managed package, it's not unusual to not be able to deploy features one needs to enable in a Salesforce Org. Person Accounts is one example that comes to mind. Fortunately, if you ask, Salesforce will enable them for you in all your sandboxes when you have them enable a feature for you.